# Lua connecting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, lua

I have a Lua web app.

I would like to connect and query my MySQL database.  I've googled and etc and have not found a good way to do so from Lua.

Any idea how I can connect and query my MySQL from within my Lua web app?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want to use the latest version of LuaSQL, which can be found on [its github page](http://github.com/keplerproject/luasql). It has quite a few enhancements over the outdated version on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

The above link is broken - here is what you're after:

```
luasql = require "luasql.mysql"

env = assert (luasql.mysql())
con = assert (env:connect("dbname","username","password","host.com"))
cur = assert (con:execute("INSERT INTO `table`(`col_int`,`col_varchar`) VALUES (9,'Hi')"))
```

You can leave out the "host.com" parameter. If you need to change the port, you can add a port number parameter after the host parameter in connect.

This is from a linux environment.